# When did the Ghorman Massacre occur?

Tags: star-wars

Wookieepedia has conflicting information as to when the Ghorman Massacre occurred. One source says:

> The Ghorman Massacre was an incident committed by Captain Wilhuff Tarkin, circa **18 BBY**.

However, another source says:

> The Ghorman Massacre was an incident that took place in **2 BBY**, in which troops of the Galactic Empire slaughtered peaceful protesters on the planet Ghorman.

When did the massacre actually occur?

Comment: One is canon (from Star Wars Timelines), the other is from a Legends (e.g. non-canon) source

Comment: Long, long ago?

Comment: @user14111 The fact that there's a different Legends and Canon answer threw me off. I kind of wish that the writers of today's Star Wars shows would follow Legends as much as possible, since there is such a strong following of Legends -- not to mention that the Legends material is just paint-by-number for the writers.

Answer (score 5):

The 18 BBY date is for [the older, Legends continuity version of the event](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ghorman_Massacre/Legends). It was first described in 1990's [*The Rebel Alliance Sourcebook*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Rebel_Alliance_Sourcebook), and elaborated upon in later works. Wookieepedia doesn't seem to have a source for the 18 BBY date, though in [*The New Essential Chronology* (2005)](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_New_Essential_Chronology) it's listed near the beginning of the section "Dawn of Dissent (19—0 B.B.Y.)", and [*The Complete Star Wars Encyclopedia* (2008)](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Complete_Star_Wars_Encyclopedia) describes it as "an early atrocity by the Empire".

As for [the Canon event of the same name](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ghorman_Massacre), according to the upcoming reference book [*Star Wars: Timelines* (2023)](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Timelines), it took place in approximately 2 BBY:

[image: Timeline of events around 2 BBY]

<sub>Source: [Amazon listing preview of Star Wars: Timelines](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0744060877)</sub>

If you're wondering about it in relation to *Andor*, it's the explicit intent of the showrunners that the Ghorman Massacre hasn't happened yet as of the timeline of the first season (5 BBY):

> Jeff Goldsmith: Y'know, anyone that's seen the animated show *Rebels* knows that [Mon Mothma] resigns. And—
>
> *Andor* writer Tony Gilroy: No, she resigns in 2 BBY. She's three years away from that.
>
> Jeff Goldsmith: No, I know.
>
> Tony Gilroy: The Battle of— the Massacre of Ghorman isn't gonna happen for two more years, three more years.

<sub>Source: https://twitter.com/jeronandor/status/1576790662271635457, excerpt from *The Q&A with Jeff Goldsmith* podcast episode: [Andor Q&A - Tony Gilroy - (S1 eps 1-4)](http://www.theqandapodcast.com/2022/09/andor-q-tony-gilroy-s1-eps-1-4.html)</sub>

Comment: Thank you so much for your very detailed answer. This Q & A will no doubt be helpful to many Star Wars fans who hear about the Ghorman Massacre, and are not aware of how and when it occurs according to Canon.